# Pandas - aggregate multiple columns with pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"ind0": list("QQQWWWW"), "ind1": list("RRRRSSS"), "vals": range(7), "cols": list("XXYXXYY")})    
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ind0 ind1  vals cols
0    Q    R     0    X
1    Q    R     1    X
2    Q    R     2    Y
3    W    R     3    X
4    W    S     4    X
5    W    S     5    Y
6    W    S     6    Y
```

I want to aggregate the values while creating columns from `col`, so I thought of using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
df_res = df.pivot_table(index=["ind0", "ind1"], columns="cols", values="vals", aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)    
print(df_res)
```

This gives me:

```
cols         X     Y
ind0 ind1           
Q    R     1.0   2.0
W    R     3.0   0.0
     S     4.0  11.0
```

However, I would rather get the sum independent of `ind1` categories while keeping the information in this column. So, the desired output would be:

```
cols         X    Y
ind0 ind1          
Q    R       1.0  2.0
W    R,S     7.0  11.0
```

Is there a way to use `pivot_table` or `pivot` to this end or do I have to aggregate for `ind1` in a second step? If the latter, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `reset_index` of `df_res` and `groupby` "ind0" and using `agg`, use different functions on columns: `join`ing unique values of "ind1" and `sum`ming "X" and "Y".

```
out = df_res.reset_index().groupby('ind0').agg({'ind1': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()), 'X':'sum', 'Y':'sum'})
```

Or if you have multiple columns that you need to do the same function on, you could also use a dict comprehension:

```
funcs = {'ind1': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()), **{k:'sum' for k in ('X','Y')}}
out = df_res.reset_index().groupby('ind0').agg(funcs)
```

Output:

```
cols  ind1    X     Y
ind0                 
Q        R  1.0   2.0
W     R, S  7.0  11.0
```

Comment: Can this be adapted for a flexible content of `cols`? Something like `[cat:'sum' for cat in df.cols.unique()]` (which obviously doesn't work) instead of `'X':'sum', 'Y':'sum'`?

Comment: @Mr.T You can use dict comprehension. The above code can also be written as: `funcs = {'ind1': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()), **{k:'sum' for k in ('X','Y')}}; df_res.reset_index().groupby('ind0').agg(funcs)`

Comment: Yup, that works with `df.cols.unique()`. Can you add it to your answer, so I can accept it?